# Protocol still is tcp after configured the kafka two-way SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, tcpdump

After configured the kafka (kafka_2.13-2.4.1) with two-way SSL per the document https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_ssl, when sent message by the kafka-console-producer.sh, the message can be received by consumer (kafka-console-consumer.sh).
But when use the tcpdump capture the network traffic, the protocol still is TCP, not TLSor SSL.

When added the -Djava.net.debug to the kafka-console-producer.sh, the two-way SSL handshakes can be printed (from ClientHello to server finishng).

Why I cannot get the tsl protocol? Is it wrong way?

Comment: SSL is layered on top of TCP

Comment: Did you mean TLS instead of Tsl?

Comment: Thanks for reply.  

Do you mean the SSL is canot be captured by "SSL is layered on top of TCP"？

You are wrong, tsl was my typo.